# Per-page bug with search

Tags: support, search, pagination

I think I've found a bug with the "results per page" boxes in the search. I tried searching for nhibernate and one to many:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=nhibernate%20one%20to%20many

Clicking on 10,30,50 all returns about 3-5 results, and then paging through seems to bring back an arbitary amount of results.

Page 4 appears blank altogether. It looks like to the relevance tab is the main issue.

**Update:** I'm using Chrome 9

[image]

Comment: What happens if you click the "relevance" tab again? (Or click "newest", then go back to "relevance"?) I have a feeling I've seen this issue before.

Comment: @Jon a load of questions appears, but then quickly disappear leaving just those 3

Comment: Sounds like you have "hide questions with ignored tags" turned on. Check your user preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have "hide ignored questions" checked in your profile, so this is correct behavior.

Uncheck it.

Comment: That's a bit of an embarrasing pebcak error. Could it perhaps say how many questions have been hidden near the top?